# Cómo asignar dinamicamente un valor a una propiedad de una clase que está compilada en una .dll desde C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb6

Me explico: Existe un proyecto hecho en C#, el cual tiene referenciados unos proyectos que fueron hechos en vb6, son proyectos compilados, es decir .dll

Por ejemplo: miproyecto.dll contiene una clase clsMiproyecto.cls

Desde C# necesito asignar un valor dinamicamente a esa propiedad. La idea es que en la clase hecha en C# van a existir las mismas propiedades que contiene la clase hecha en vb6, es decir:

```
Clase hecha en C#:

public PubStrDescripcion;

Clase hecha en Vb6:

public PubStrDesc;
```

Mediante la BD se guardaran las equivalencias, es decir el nombre de la propiedad en C# y el nombre de la propiedad en VB6 y cuando se realice un llamado a esa clase de vb6 desde C# los valores se asignen automáticamente con esta información de las equivalencias guardada.

algo así como: `XXXXX("NombrePropiedadVB6").Value = XXXX("NombrePropiedadC#).Value`

Código utilizado:

```
SrvUnoEE.clsCliente vobjCliente=legacy.SrvUnoEE.CrearCliente(); 
Type type = vobjCliente.GetType(); 
type.GetProperty("pubStrUsuario");
```

`GetProperty` retorna `null`

Edito:

Esto es lo que retorna al ejecutar el ILSpy:

```
Imports ADODB
Imports SrvGeneral
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace SrvUnoEE
    <Guid("99B90350-25D1-458C-A502-FE1AC04D7E47"), TypeLibType(4304S)>
    <ComImport()>
    Public Interface _clsCliente
        <DispId(1073938432)>
        Property pubObApp() As Application

        <DispId(1073938433)>
        Property pubIntCia() As Short

        <DispId(1073938434)>
        Property pubLngRowid() As Integer

        <DispId(1073938435)>
        Property PubStrSucursal() As String

        <DispId(1073938436)>
        Property PubStrDesSucursal() As String

        <DispId(1073938437)>
        Property PubStrMoneda() As String

        <DispId(1073938438)>
        Property pubStrVendedor() As String
    End Interface
End Namespace
```

Comment: Tras pensarlo, creo que puede ser posible. Pero sería interesante ver como estas instanciando la dll en vb6 para tener mas información y añadirte una respuesta

Comment: Hola @Pikoh, de antemano te agradezco tu ayuda. Bueno te tengo que aclarar que es un proyecto que ya tiene una estructura especifica y no conozco como tal el sitio en donde este hace la instancia del proyecto. Lo único que te puedo decir es que este proyecto en vb6 es un proyecto compilado. Esta dll contiene clases con cierta lógica que necesitamos utilizarla desde nuestro proyecto en C#. de esta manera yo llamo a la clase, la cual me devuelve una instancia.  `SrvUnoEE.clsCliente vobjCliente = legacy.SrvUnoEE.CrearCliente();` y a partir de esta deseo acceder a las propiedades de objeto.

Comment: Viendo el desensamblado de ILspy, no veo por ningun lado `pubStrUsuario`. Puedes probar con otra,por ejemplo `pubStrVendedor`? Por otro lado,analiza el porqué hay algunas propiedades que si aparecen y otras no,si estas seguro de que `pubStrUsuario` debería estar.

Comment: No pegué todo lo que retorna el ilspy pero si la tiene, probé con otra variable, pubintcia pero tampoco me da ningún resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Para poder realizar lo que quieres y acceder al valor y modificar el valor de  propiedades de un objeto mediante su nombre se pueden utilizar los métodos [`GetProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.type.getproperty(v=vs.110).aspx) y [`GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx)/[`SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xb5dd1f1(v=vs.110).aspx) de la siguiente manera:

```
object valor= typeof(tipoDelObjeto).GetProperty("NombrePropiedad").GetValue(instancia, null);
typeof(tipoDelObjeto).GetProperty("NombrePropiedad").SetValue(instancia, "valor", null);
```

En tu caso, no tengo todos los datos pero sería algo asi:

```
PubStrDescripcion objetoC= new PubStrDescripcion();
SrvUnoEE.clsCliente vobjCliente = legacy.SrvUnoEE.CrearCliente();
//obtenemos el valor de la propiedad C#
object valor= typeof(PubStrDescripcion).GetProperty("NombrePropiedad").GetValue(objetoC, null); 
//Ponemos el valor en el objeto vb6
typeof(SrvUnoEE.clsCliente).GetProperty("NombrePropiedad").SetValue(vobjCliente , valor, null);
```

Como digo no tengo todos los datos reales (por ejemplo los nombres de tus clases, forma de instanciarlas etc..) pero espero que esto te de un punto de partida para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Yo tengo una duda con esta respuesta y espero me puedas aclarar, es interesante tu respuesta pero mi duda es si el proyecto en VB no tiene SET y GET definidos, aun así se podría asignar u obtener esos valores? @Pikoh

Comment: @LuisFernando pues en realidad no podría asegurarlo ya que nunca lo intenté con una dll vb6,pero creo que si. `GetProperty` no obtiene solo propiedades sino tambien variables si no me equivoco. Otra cosa son los Campos, que necesitarían `GetField` en lugar de `GetProperty`. En cuanto a asignar/obtener valores, GetValue y SetValue no tienen que ver con `get/set`, son métodos par obtener el valor y ponerlo.

Comment: Excelente, seria bueno probar eso.

Comment: Hola, de nuevo gracias, lo que tú me me dices ya lo había probado pero cuando coloco `type.GetProperty("NombreVariable")` este retorna null y al tratar de darle un `SetValue(Obj,"mi valor);` sale el error  **type.GetField("pubStrCodigoEAN").SetValue(vobjCliente,"xx") threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' void {System.NullReferenceException}**. Aclaro que la variable si existe en la clase que estoy instanciando.

Comment: Por eso te comentaba @AndresRuales que falta informacion en tu pregunta,ya que habria que saber si la variable es publica o privada,como estas enlazando la dll (.net debería crear un objeto interop al añadir la referencia) etc,etc. Te recomiendo que pulses en [edit] y añadas lo que has probado,que errores te da y toda la información que puedas proporcionar. Tambien sería bueno que proporcionaras un [mcve]

Comment: @AndresRuales otra cosa...que es `type` cuando estas probando `type.GetProperty`?

Comment: @Pikoh respondo a tus preguntas, la variable es pública, se está creando un objeto interop y estoy enlazando la dll por medio de una referencia, es decir al proyecto le di Add reference.. y busque la .dll. el comentario de @luisFernando me dejo pensando porque en el proyecto sólo se define la variable, es decir: `Public pubStrUsuario As String` como propiedad de la clase pero en ningun momento existe un `Property Get pubStrUsuario() As String `. Si necesitas más info con gusto, me gustaría ser más especifico pero como te cuento es un proyecto que me entregaron y no conozco toda su config.

Comment: Este es mi código:`SrvUnoEE.clsCliente vobjCliente=legacy.SrvUnoEE.CrearCliente();
Type type = vobjCliente.GetType();
type.GetProperty("pubStrUsuario");` En la línea del GetProperty es cuando retorna NULL.

Comment: @AndresRuales has probado con `GetField` en lugar de `GetProperty` en ese caso?

Comment: @Pikoh Sí y tampoco funciona.

Comment: @AndresRuales Pues es dificil poder ayudarte sin tener acceso a la libreria o a un [mcve]. Lo unico que se me ocurre es que uses alguna herramienta tipo ILSpy para abrir el archivo interop que se debe haber creado y asi puedas investigar si desde ahi tienes acceso a la variable en concreto que buscas. Si desde ahi lo ves, puedes investigar el tipo y como poder acceder a ella.

Comment: Que use ILSpy para sacar todo el codigo mejor :)

Comment: Bueno te cuento que utilice el ILSpy, que por cierto no lo conocía y muy bueno, y me arrojo esto:`Imports ADODB
Imports SrvGeneral
Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace SrvUnoEE
 <Guid("99B90350-25D1-458C-A502-FE1AC04D7E47"), TypeLibType(4304S)>
 <ComImport()>
 Public Interface _clsCliente
  <DispId(1073938432)>
  Property pubObApp() As Application

  <DispId(1073938433)>
  Property pubIntCia() As Short`

Comment: GetProperty y SetProperty son métodos de reflection, y reflection solo funciona con .net, y vb6 no tiene nada que ver con .net.

Comment: @Luis no se si leiste la pregunta entera. La pregunta habla de una libreria vb6 referenciada desde una .net. Para hace eso,se crea un wrapper .net sobre la librería vb6,con lo que si puede usarse reflection. De hecho,habla de que usa ilspy para inspeccionar,lo cual demuestra estar tratando de .net.De todas maneras si lees mi respuesta fue una pregunta a la que le faltaba mucha información para darle una respuesta inequívoca.

Comment: Es distinta la manera en que se trabajan los objetos COM que los objetos .net. Se podría usar reflection pero hasta donde se, no es con GetProperty/SetProperty directamente, usas: Type type = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("NombreClase");

Answer (score 0):

Toda DLL de VB6 por defecto es de tipo COM. El framework de .NET te proporciona una herramienta llamada [Tlbimp.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer) que te permite dado una DLL generar un ensamblado .NET que contiene los metadatos en tiempo de ejecución para los tipos definidos en la biblioteca de tipos original. Con este ensamblado resultante simplemente lo agregas como referencia a tu proyecto C# y puedes trabajar directamente con las propiedades como cualquier clase .NET

Comment: Diría que no es necesario usar tblimp Sergio. Cuando tu añades una referencia a un objeto COM desde el visual studio el proceso se realiza automaticamente y genera el interop.